# How to lock accounts after 3 times of invalid login in Oracle Apex?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have an application in Oracle Apex.

But the invalid login error message interferes with counting the 3 times in which the user entered his credentials wrong.

[image]

I have tried using this code. And it expects that at the 3rd time of invalid start login, it will block the user's account. And then only up to the 6th time it blocks the account. When it should only be the 3rd time the blockade.

```
create or replace function LOGIN2021 ( p_username varchar2, p_password varchar2 ) return boolean is  
   i integer;  
   l_rcnt number;
   l_failed_cnt number;
   l_max_failed_cnt number :=4;
   l_lock_flag varchar2(1);
   
begin
    select count(1) into l_rcnt
    from usuarios t1
    where upper(t1.USUARIO) = upper(p_username)
     and upper(t1.CLAVE) = upper(p_password)
     and t1.enabled_flag = 'Y';
     
        if (l_rcnt > 0) then
            select is_locked into l_lock_flag from usuarios where upper(usuario) = upper(p_username)
            and upper(clave) = upper(p_password);
            
            if (l_lock_flag = 'N') then
                delete from usuarios_log where upper(usuario)= upper(p_username);
                return true;
            elsif (l_lock_flag = 'Y') then
                apex_util.set_custom_auth_status (p_status => 'Your account is now locked! Please contact the system administrator to unlock your account. Thank you.');
                return false;
            end if;
        else
            merge into usuarios_log u
            using dual l 
            on (u.usuario=p_username)
                when matched then
                    update set login_fallido_cont = login_fallido_cont+1, update_on = sysdate
                when not matched then
                    insert (usuario, login_fallido_cont, update_on) values
                    (p_username,1,sysdate);
            
            select login_fallido_cont into l_failed_cnt
            from usuarios_log where usuario = p_username;
                if (l_failed_cnt > l_max_failed_cnt) then
                    update usuarios set is_locked = 'Y' where usuario = p_username;
                end if;
              return  ( false ) ;
        end if;
    exception when others then
        return ( false );
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code is written, it should only set the account to locked on the 5th wrong attempt.

Given:

```
   l_max_failed_cnt number :=4;
```

Then the following statement

```
  if (l_failed_cnt > l_max_failed_cnt) then
```

will only yield true if l_failed_cnt is 5 or higher. If you want it locked after  the 3rd invalid login then you need to set `l_max_failed_cnt := 2;`

Notes:

- The code above uses UPPER for password and username mixed. In the `else` block there is no UPPER anymore which will lead to unexpected results
- As a good practice, user passwords should *never ever* be stored in clear text in the database. Inform yourself how to check and store passwords. Clear text is absolutely out of the question. Would you use a system if you knew that your password is readable to anyone with access to the db ? [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/storing-passwords-in-the-database-9i) is a good article showing what can be done but there probably are more up to date blogs explaining how to do this.